# Java Open Sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets

I need to create an Android app to connect to a device and turn on or off its processes. I have the IP#, open ports, and the process id#'s and names of the device. This device works off an old linux kernel.

Do I need to use an open socket to make this connection with the other device? If this is the direction I need to go, is the client side the device and server side the android app or reverse?

Any confirmation that this is the direction I need to pursue? or if this is not what I need will you kindly point me in the right direction?

Comment: Holy wall-of-text, batman!

Comment: 'open ports, '. Please explain what you mean by that. And how it would help you.

Comment: 'to make this type of connection'. What kind of connection exactly?

Comment: I need to make an app that will be able to control the other devices processes. Its a medical mannequin that can blink, sweat, bleed, etc. I need the app to bypass the software that came with it and make this mannequin blink or change his respiration rate with a push of the app button. So I was thinking I need an open socket connection to send commands to the mannequin to blink or sweat.

Comment: Unanswerable without knowing more about the device. Does it expose listening TCP ports? UDP ports! Other? Do you have a protocol specification for what to send to it?

Comment: I was able to use nmap the map the open ports of the mannequin. Would I use one of these open ports, for example port 26 telnet was open.

Comment: EJP, I know I would use the TCP and as far as the protocol specification for what to send it, I know I do have the process names and id# to send it commands. When I used telnet to get into the processes I used ./dilate_eyes.out to make it's eye dilate. So I was thinking that once I got a connection then I could send the command above to either execute a process or kill a process.

Comment: So there's your answer. You open a client socket to the telnet port and send those commands. All that detail should have been stated in the question. We can't tell you what the commands are, or the por(s), or the protocol.

Comment: Thank you, that's all I wanted was confirmation that I was headed in the right direction. I didn't want answers just confirmation. Thanks for taking your time out to confirm.